# Find the last 3 digits of $2003^{2002^{2001}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

help..

Find the last 3 digits of $$2003^{2002^{2001}}$$

I try..

I need find $$2003^{2002^{2001}}\equiv x(mod\ 1000)$$ ??

How?

Comment: I believe this is a very similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108868/find-the-last-3-digits-of-the-number-200320022001

Comment: Hint: $\varphi(1000)=400$ and $2003\equiv 3\pmod{1000}$. It's very similar to your previous question (although not identical, because $2002$ is not coprime to $400$).

Comment: First step is right... taking the result **mod** $1000$ will get you the last three digits.

Answer (score 1):

So you started with the right step, but you need to know [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) at least, to make a lot more progress.

We immediately have:

$$2003^{2002^{2001}} \equiv 3^{2002^{2001}} \bmod 1000$$

Because there are only a limited number of values $\bmod 1000$, exponentiation goes through a cycle. [Carmichael's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length) $\lambda(n)$ tells us how long that cycle can be, and that shorter cycles divide that cycle length. $\lambda(1000) =100$ so we can say:

$$3^{2002^{2001}} \equiv 3^{2002^{2001} \bmod 100} \equiv 3^{2^{2001}} \bmod 1000$$

We can apply this again to the higher exponent, with $\lambda(100)=20$, but not as simply because $2$ has to have at least two powers of $2$ included:

$$ {2^{2001}}  \equiv 2^{21}\bmod 100$$

More approachably, we can use the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to combine the results $ {2^{2001}}  \equiv 2 \bmod 25$ and $ {2^{2001}}  \equiv 0 \bmod 4$ to find that

$$ {2^{2001}}  \equiv 52\bmod 100$$

This gives us that
$$2003^{2002^{2001}} \equiv 3^{52} \bmod 1000$$

after which that can be calculated by [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) in a few steps. Alternatively we can take advantage of $9=10-1$ to get: 
$$3^{52} = 9^{26} = (10-1)^{26} = \overbrace{1000k}^{\text{higher terms}} + 100\binom{26}{2} - 10\binom{26}{1} +1 \\
\implies 3^{52}\equiv 100\cdot 325 -10\cdot 26 +1 \equiv 500 -260+1 \equiv \fbox{241} \bmod 1000$$

as the result.